# Get stuck in a 'while True' loop python

Tags: python, while-loop

I just learned about `break` and `return` in Python.

In a toy code that I wrote to get familiar with the two statements, I got stuck in a loop, but I don't know why. Here is my code:

```
def break_return():
    while True:
        for i in range(5):
            if i < 2:
                print(i)
            if i == 3:
                break
        else:
            print('i = ', i)
            return 343
break_return()
```

I'm new to programming, any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: For problems like this, it's very helpful to run your program in [an interactive visualizer](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#) or the built-in debugger, to see the flow of control visually instead of just guessing at what it might be that could cause this behavior.

Comment: @abarnert this is very helpful! Thank you!

Comment: I wish more people knew about PythonTutor. (Well, if _every_ Python novice knew about it, it might bankrupt Philip Guo or whoever's hosting it for him, because it's so useful that everyone would be using it all the time while learning…)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the `for-else` construct you only enter the `else` block if the `for` loop does not `break`, which your `for` loop always does because `i` inevitably becomes `3` with your `range` generator. Your infinite `while` loop is therefore never able to reach the `return` statement, which is only in the said `else` block.

Answer (score -2):

nvm I'm super wrong here

First of all, when you define a function in Python, any code that belongs in the function should be in the same indentation block. With this in mind, your code would look like this:

```
def break_return():
    while True: 
        for i in range(5):
            if i < 2:
                print(i)
            if i == 3:
                break
        else:
            print('i = ', i)
            return 343
break_return()
```

The next problem I see is that your `else` statement isn't correctly formatted with an `if` statement. If you mean for it to go on the 2nd `if` statement, your code would look like this:

```
def break_return():
    while True: 
        for i in range(5):
            if i < 2:
                print(i)
            if i == 3:
                break
            else:
                print('i = ', i)
                return 343
break_return()
```

This is only formatting. But in this example, the code would only run once because it immediately returns and exits the function.

I think this may be a better example of using both `break` and `return`:

```
def break_return(value):
    for i in range(5):
        print(i)
        if i == 3:
            break #This exits the for loop
        if i == 4:
            print("This won't print!")
            #Won't print because the loop "breaks" before i ever becomes 4
    return value * 2 #Returns the input value x 2

print(break_return(30)) #Display the return value of break_return()
```

This demonstrates how `break` exits a `for` loop and how `return` can return a value from the function.

The output of the code above is:

```
0  #Value of i
1  #Value of i
2  #Value of i
3  #Value of i
60 #The value returned by the function
```

Glad to hear you're learning Python! It's a lot of fun, and super useful.

Comment: The OP is asking about a `for…else` statement.